# Deleting children that are still on the scene

Tags: actionscript-3, action

I'm trying to delete my object when it reaches the end of the animation. I delete the parent when I run out of lives. When I do so, it crashes because there are still children of the parent on the scene. So I would like to know a way to delete all the children that are still on the scene when I run out of lives.

(sorry if the code is in french). [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhxsQ.png)

Comment: I think you need to call `this.parent.removeChild` *after* you all your other code on that block.  The code is executed in order from top to bottom in each block of code, so if you remove the `this.` and *then* try to do an operation on it like adding or removing eventListeners... it won't be able to. I could be wrong and cant test it now, but give that a try

Comment: Just a removeChild(this); should be enough, although this is a bad practice, the children should be removed where they were created - in the parent.

Try to remove the event listeners first, then remove child. What happens on the "dispartition" event, do you do something with the current object that was already removed ?

Answer (score 0):

parent.removeChildren(0,parent.numChildren-1)